# How do I properly spec as a Balance druid?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm not new in the World of Warcraft World, but currently I'm trying a new class, a Druid (Level 79 as of yesterday).

I'm leveling as a Tank, but I'm looking for a DPS off-spec. I don't like the idea of  melee DPS since I have a Warrior and a Death Knight, so I was thinking about speccing as a Balance druid. With all the changes and the "Moon Circle" rotation, I have no clue on how to gear/spec it. I haven't found something useful by browsing forums, so any suggestions regarding the construction of a decent Level 85 Balance druid spec would be awesome.

An extra note: Getting gear is not a problem, as I'm planning on leveling and running heroics as a bear until I get a set for the bird to raid with. :)

Comment: The core of the balance druid rotation is pretty easy: Cast **Starfire** until you reach eclipse, then cast **Wrath** until you reach eclipse, repeat ad infinitum. **Starsurge** should be cast whenever it's not on cooldown, and you want to strive to keep both of your DoTs (**Moonfire**/Sunfire and **Insect Swarm**) up on the target you're killing.

Comment: Just to add although that the Balance Druid "rotation" (it's actually more like a priority list) is quite simple and easy to be good at, the Balance spec is actually one of the hardest to reach absolutely tip-top, World of Logs-busting performance, especially since some of the mechanics are subtle and not obvious and you need to know the raid encounters ahead of time to time your eclipses and cooldowns, or if a lot of mobility or AoE is required and you must remain in Solar eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elitist Jerks](http://elitistjerks.com/) is usually a great place to start. Their forums have a lot of information on all the specs in the game and there are always up-to-date discussions so that you can stay on top of patch changes.

I would recommend reading the [Balance spec guide for 4.0.6](http://elitistjerks.com/f73/t110353-balance_cataclysm_release_updated_4_0_6_a/). The first section covered is  [Talents, Glyphs and Races](http://elitistjerks.com/f73/t110353-balance_cataclysm_release_updated_4_0_6_a/#Talents__Glyphs__and_Race) which from a quick read should be exactly what you need.

Comment: Care to summarize what that balance spec consist of and why it's a great choice?

Comment: @ivo I am not familiar with the Balance spec specifically (I have a priest, shaman and mage) otherwise I would be happy to oblige.